# What's the difference between data stored in global variables and data stored in the heap?

Tags: c++, variables, heap-memory, global

```
int globalInt = 1; 

int main(){
    int* heapInt = new int(1);
}
```

What is the difference between globalInt and heapInt? I know that what heapInt points to is in the heap, and I know that globalInt goes into some global data storage, but what is the difference? Why use one over the other?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: it's relevant for raii: heapInt gets released at the end of main() because it is on the heap. it has a major impact if you have another function, probably not main(). So after the function returns, every variable in the function gets deleted and destroyed.

Comment: Well, one is much simpler, isn't it...

Comment: @ultima_rat0 I'm not sure whether you're actually saying the same thing, but at the least it's confusingly phrased. The pointer `heapInt` will indeed be destroyed, but that won't release the dynamically allocated memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A global variable has static storage duration. This means that the object exists from when the program starts to when it ends. It exists for the entire duration of the program.

The `int` created with the new-expression has dynamic storage duration. It's lifetime begins with the new-expression and ends when you do `delete heapInt;`.

You can think of these two storage durations as being opposite ends of the spectrum. A global variable gives you the least control over its lifetime because it always exists. A dynamically allocated object gives you the most control, because you can create it and destroy it at any point in your code.

It's also worth noting that the global variable has a name. This makes the object accessible to all parts of your code in which that name is in scope. In contrast, to access the dynamically allocated object, you need to have been given a pointer to it.

Global variables are generally considered bad practice because they introduce global state to your program. That is, you might have a function that modifies or uses the global variable without making it clear that it does so in its interface. This means the function may have secret side effects, leading to unpredictable and unmaintainable code that it is hard to test.

On the other hand, dynamically allocated objects are often necessary but should be used carefully. It is important that you ensure the lifetime of the object is managed appropriately. One approach to this is to use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), where objects are only dynamically allocated in constructors and then correspondingly destroyed in destructors. An additional modern approach is to avoid doing the memory management yourself entirely and use smart pointers instead.

Comment: So the only difference is being able to control when you can trash it with the delete operator?

Comment: not only, see [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)

Answer (score 1):

There are two main differences - scope and lifetime.

You can use `globalInt` anywhere in the program, whereas you can use `heapInt` only inside `main`.

Lifetime for a global is from program start (well, since before `main` enters anyway) to end, whereas the dynamically allocated one starts when you `new` it and is gone when you `delete` it.

Comment: after the main function ends, i understand that heapInt is out of scope, but is the value 1 still sitting in the memory address?

Comment: @user2356635 well, after `main` ends, so does the program (pending globals' destruction) so why would it matter - it will be reclaimed by the OS anyway,

Comment: What if heapInt was initialized in a different function that was called within main. Would heapInt still exist when this function exited? and what would happen to the data at the address after exiting this function.

Comment: @user2356635 it would, and as soon as all pointers to it are lost, it would be leaked memory.

Answer (score 0):

Just to bake your noodle, did you also consider

```
int globalInt = 1;
int* globalHeapInt = new int(1);

int main() {
    int* heapInt = new int(1);
}
```

To answer the why part: Storing anything in the heap has the overhead of a pointer - 4 or 8 bytes depending on how many bits you are building for.

Global values like globalInt for plain data types are written out to the "data segment" of the executable and they're loaded, hard-wired, into the process when the OS starts the application.

globalHeapInt will be loaded with a value of NULL, and then in some secret boot-strap "pre-main" code provided by the compiler, the program will have to execute:

```
globalHeapInt = malloc(sizeof(int));
*globalHeapInt = 1;
```

On a 64-bit system, you are now using (at least) 12 bytes to store a 4 byte value.

"heapInt" executes something similar, but the pointer is stored either on the stack or in a register.

Why would you want to use global values? When you have finite, known quantities of data, then it makes sense to have them in simple globals.

So primarily heap is for dynamic storage - when you don't know in advance whether or how much still you will need. For example, imagine a program which takes a list of books as command parameters:

```
// reserve memory for upto 1000 Books.
Book globalBooks[1000];

// or use the heap when we know how many we need.
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    int numBooks = argc;
    if ( numBooks < 1 ) {
       printf("Screw you and your empty book list.\n");
       exit(1);
    }
    Books* heapBooks = new Books(numBooks);
    ...
}
```

The first form can only handle 1000 books but it always has memory for upto 1000 books. The second form can handle any number of books upto the maximum amount of memory available to the process.